# Logical equivalence or equality for inequalities

Tags: inequality

Do I need to use [logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) or [equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)) for the next inequalities?

**case 1**

$$x < y ≡/= x + 1 < y + 1$$

**case 1**

$$x < y ≡/= x < y + 10$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is an equivalence. 
If you would write
$x<y=x+1<y+1$, you would directly have the middle part, that is $y=x+1$, which I dont think you mean here.

The second one is neither. Equality is wrong due to the same reason as above.

$x<y≡x<y+10$ is wrong too, because equivalence holds for both directions. If $x<y$, $x<y+10$ holds, but not the other way around!

The right thing to say here would be:
$x<y \Rightarrow x<y+10$.